# copy and paste multiple values from one table cell to another

Tags: user-expectation

In a table, on a single cell, there are between 1-7 values,
I am using a contextual menu above the table with a "copy rules" button and a "paste rules" button. 
when a cell is selected, the "copy rules" button is enabled, once the user click it and the then click another cell, the "paste rules" button is enabled, now the user can paste the values.[image]

1. Is there a way to show the user what is inside the clipboard at any
   moment?
2. Can you think of a better way to perform this copy & paste
   table cells values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to (1), typically, you would show what's in the clipboard by creating a "marching-ants" border around the cells that were selected for the copy operation (as in Microsoft Excel).

For (2), the system in place is *sufficient*, but the user may also expect there to be facilities for a right-click copy/paste (in the context menu) and the ability to use the popular `Ctrl + C` and `Ctrl + V` hotkeys.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like the details in the column "rules" can be assigned to two different topics:

- user rights (e.g. "manage users")
- the user role (e.g. "api user")

You could use a combobox to assign the user role. For the selection of user rights I would suggest using checkboxes. They are more comfortable to edit and the rights of the different persons can be easily compared.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv6pmc.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>